# Export SAS data to SPSS, date and datetime

Tags: sas, spss

I have data inside SAS.

I want to store the datafile to SPSS format (*.sav)

I use the following program:

```
PROC export Data=SASdataToStoreInSPSS
FILE="Path\Filename_%sysfunc(today(),date9.).sav"
dbms=sav replace;
RUN;
```

This works great. Except when I open the file in SPSS the dates are strangly formatted.

For example:

```
156405 08:51:00
```

Should be

```
3-Jan-2011 08:51
```

I can manually change the data formats in SPSS. So the values are correct date values, except they are not automatically formatted in a readable format.

I tried to change the format in SAS before saving to DATETIME20. or DATETIME23.3. But this does not help.

I want this to work without having to open SPSS and run a Syntax there. 
The SPSS files that SAS spits out have to be directly mailed to other users of the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SAS mentioned it has to do with the SPSS driver they use. Apparently it is not an easy fix so they forwarded the issue to second-line tech support.

The workaround you will need is split the dates in two columns. One with date and one with time.

```
data SPSS2;
set SPSS;

date = put(datepart(DatumSPSS), date9.); 
time = put(timepart(DatumSPSS), time8.); 
run;
```

Or you can tell the end user how to change the format of the date in SPSS.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is either a bug with SAS's export, or an issue with SPSS where some default changed.  What's happening is that SAS is storing it as a SPSS Date - but with width 16, which is not long enough to hold the complete datetime.  I don't think you can use `DBDSOPTS` with DBMS=SPSS, so I don't know that there is a good workaround short of importing the file into SPSS.

You could do that automatically, though, using the SPSS Production facility; I've written an import script before and asked SAS to run `spssprod` with the batch file.  That's an irritating workaround, but it might be the easiest, unless SAS Tech Support can help you (and certainly try that - they are usually only a few hours' turnaround for initial contact at least).

Comment: Thank you I contacted SAS Tech Support

Answer (score -1):

For an automated approach, try this .NET app. You need SPSS, but SAS is not required to convert a large collection of SAS files automatically.
[Manual Process included code samples](http://the-chronicon.blogspot.com/2013/08/mass-conversion-convert-many-sas-xpt.html) or [Application Download](http://the-chronicon.blogspot.com/p/sas2spss.html)